# Web scraping - "href" links are not shown completely and I can't scrape for the processing that I want to do in these data

Tags: python, http, web, web-scraping, inspect

**it is shown like that and the compiler consider it as text but not links so what should I do to turn to likes like (http//..) so I can access them and catch data**

**

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="css-o171kl" href="/jobs/p/qZ2W8Q0izdWR-Senior-Python-Developer---Remote-Nile-Bits-LLC-Giza-Egypt?o=1&amp;l=sp&amp;t=sj&amp;a=python|search-v3|spbg">Senior Python Developer - Remote</a>
```

**

Comment: Have you written any code? Pls post it.

Comment: Try using bs4 to convert text html to tag